How to use variable from <appSettings> in Web.config to configure sessionState?
I want to have a key in appSettings of web.config:
<add key="EnableCookieBasedSession" value="true" />

Based on this key I want my ASP.NET 4.8 web app to use cookie based session.
I tried this - but it keeps failing:
<sessionState
    mode="StateServer"
    stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424"
    timeout="480"
    regenerateExpiredSessionId="true"
    cookieless="<%= (string)System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EnableCookieBasedSession"] == \"true\" ? \"false\" : \"true\" %>" />

What's the correct way of handling this?

I don't think that is achievable in Web.config. While you can directly provide the boolean value in cookieless instead of depending on the EnableCookieBasedSession value in <appSettings> section.

I don't believe that you can use server side expressions like that. On the other hand, it not all that clear why one section of web config is to be changed that is THEN used in another section? In other words, in place of changing your enableCookieBased session, why not just make the change in the sessionState key? If this is for dev vs production, then of course you can use/have a transform in the "release" version of the web.config, and thus you can enjoy 2 different settings (one for dev/debug, and one for release anyway.

So it is not Dev vs Prod. I am trying to move from cookieless session to cookie based one, but I want it configurable.

Take a step back and think about what you are trying to do:
You are trying to use an app setting IN the config file to change the behavior of a section IN the config file.
Why not just have the proper configuration in the section that is IN the config file?
I would recommend you create a new configuration in your solution and let the build process output the section with the desired configuration. Make sure you base the new configuration on the desired environment (e.g. Debug, Release).
Once the new configuration is created (eg. COOKIESESSION), you can add a new web configuration file called web.COOKIESESSION.config and have your session section configured as you want:
<sessionState
mode="StateServer"
stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424"
timeout="480"
regenerateExpiredSessionId="true"
cookieless="false" xdt:Transform="Replace" />

Your regular config file (e.g. web.Release.config) can then have the cookie-less session state defined by default:
<sessionState
mode="StateServer"
stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424"
timeout="480"
regenerateExpiredSessionId="true"
cookieless="true" />

Or the other way around. Whatever the default is for you.
When publishing, make sure you select the desired configuration. The build process should give you the right session element.
